# Android .setmesage with subscript or superscript text

Tags: java, android

How does one display subscripts or superscripts in .setmessage?

```
  show = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                                .setTitle("Error")
                                .setMessage(
                                        "Please enter a value for P<sub><small>1</small></sub>.")
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Comment: I found the answer using Html fromHtml. And will post the answer in 8 hours

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your message is a string resource rather than a hard-wired string. In that case, `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags should work in the string resource value itself (though the exact list of supported tags is, unfortunately, undocumented).

If you need to display a message that you obtain from somewhere else, create an HTML fragment with `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags and run that through `Html.fromHtml()`, passing the result to `setMessage()`.